# how to write int values in hadoop reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a **mapreduce** with **Hadoop**.
In reduce method, I want to use *context.write()* . But output is int type.
How can I do this? When I use  *context.write()* it shows an error:

The second argument cannot be int.

This is my code:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int count = 0;

            for (NullWritable nullWritable : values) {
                count++;
            }

             //context.write(key, count); 
}
```

This reduce counts something. Then it should write key and count variable.

How can I do that?

**Answer**

I found my answer. I should *new* a *IntWritable* class and use its method (*set(intValue)*).

Like following code:

```
IntWritable c = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                int count = 0;


                for (NullWritable nullWritable : values) {
                    count++;
                }

                c.set(count);
                context.write(key, c);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it like this:

```
context.write(key,new IntWritable(count));
```

Comment: Thanks. But it wastes memory! If your reduce called many times, it was creating new object and wasting memory... however thanks ;)

Comment: Your reducer will be called as many times as there are unique keys in your data. NB. Anyways it doesnot take as much memory as it takes for the map and mapreduce are memory and cpu intensive tasks so you should keep that in mind